# Widget shows empty in live server

Tags: wordpress

when I uploaded the wordpress file and database to live server, all the widget shows empty. It is working properly in local server. help me to display the widget.

Comment: how did you import database to live from local ?

Comment: I uploaded through cpanel.

Comment: did you change url from old to new one in DB?

Comment: created database, change the configuration settings and export the db file from local server and import it to  live db.

Comment: its wrong. site url and many fields in DB are still localhost, change them to live server url.

Comment: yes. i try to add widget manually in but i cant save the changes

Comment: it will never work like this, follow procedure http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/

Comment: I have changed the site url in wp options already

Comment: not only `wp_options` table. please check above link and follow all steps. you may have many other tables where old urls exists.

Comment: milap it worked,thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you might have changed the site url, and the content in the text widgets are stored in serialize form.. so you need to copy the content from local to live again

Comment: I tried to copy the content from local to live but i cant save it

Comment: open up the exported DB in dreamweaver or any text editor and find and replace the local URL to your new URL... then import the updated SQL file ..and insert the widgets values again